# §non_lazy_ptr iphone sdk 3.0

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, non-lazy-ptr

After I built my iphone 2.2.1 application in sdk 3.0, I get a lot of errors of type §non_lazy_ptr. I am getting it on the CFFTPStream constants, like kCFStreamPropertyFTPPassword and kCFStreamPropertyUserName. Anyone know what causes this?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem that you have and I solved it by adding the CFNetwork.framework directly to my target.

Expand Targets
RMB on your target
LMB add, select Existing Frameworks
LMB CFNetwork.framework

For some reason it seems to be important that you add it via RMB on your target.